# Fixing Vivado test bench add/sub errors (VHDL)?

Tags: vhdl, vivado, test-bench

I am attempting to create a test bench file to simulate my add/sub module and have received the two following errors:

- ERROR: [USF-XSim-62] 'elaborate' step failed with error(s). Please check the Tcl console output for more information
- ERROR: [Vivado 12-4473] Detected error while running simulation. Please correct the issue and retry this operation

I was trying to make my code look a little nicer and less redundant by using a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR. I am wondering if I implemented this incorrectly or is something else wrong with my VHDL code?

Or could my issue be in declaring my entity incorrectly? I first created a full adder with VHDL code and then used block diagrams to make my add/sub module. When I created a block diagram I had to apply a wrapper in order to set my constraints. So, I never actually named the entity but the "Design Sources" has it listed as "AddSub_1_wrapper" while the unwrapped, block diagram name is "AddSub_1".

The 'elaborate' file contained the following:

```
Vivado Simulator 2018.2
Copyright 1986-1999, 2001-2018 Xilinx, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Running: C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2018.2/bin/unwrapped/win64.o/xelab.exe -wto 
53289afc3c364a2082c40394db3142eb --incr --debug typical --relax --mt 2 -L 
xil_defaultlib -L unisims_ver -L unimacro_ver -L secureip -L xpm --snapshot 
testBench_lab2_behav xil_defaultlib.testBench_lab2 xil_defaultlib.glbl -log 
elaborate.log 
Using 2 slave threads.
Starting static elaboration
ERROR: [VRFC 10-923] index value <3> is out of range [2:0] of array <abc>
[C:/Users/jstev/Desktop/lab_2.1/lab_2.1.srcs/sim_1/new/addSub_TestBench.vhd:41] 
ERROR: [VRFC 10-923] index value <3> is out of range [2:0] of array <def>
[C:/Users/jstev/Desktop/lab_2.1/lab_2.1.srcs/sim_1/new/addSub_TestBench.vhd:42] 
ERROR: [XSIM 43-3322] Static elaboration of top level Verilog design unit(s) in library work failed.
```

NOTE: The OP input pin goes to '1' to perform the subtraction, '0' for addition. Also, the add/sub module performs as expected on the physical FPGA device.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-- Module Name: testBench_lab2
-- Target Devices: FPGA xc7a35tcpg236-1
-----------------------------------------------------------------

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity testBench_lab2 is
--  Port ( );
end testBench_lab2;

architecture Behavioral of testBench_lab2 is
    -- declare component teting --
    component AddSub_1_wrapper
       Port (A_0,A_1,A_2 : in STD_LOGIC;
             B_0,B_1,B_2 : in STD_LOGIC;
             OP: in STD_LOGIC;
             S_0,S_1,S_2 : out STD_LOGIC;
             Sign : out STD_LOGIC);
    end component;

    -- declare internal signals --
    signal abc : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
    signal def : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
    signal OP: STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal S_0,S_1,S_2 : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal Sign: STD_LOGIC := '0';

begin
    UTT : AddSub_1_wrapper
        port map(A_0=>abc(3),A_1=>abc(2),A_2=>abc(3),
                 B_0=>def(3),B_1=>def(2),B_2=>def(3),
                 S_0=>S_0,S_1=>S_1,S_2=>S_0,
                 OP=>OP,Sign=>Sign);

    -- start testing process --
    process 
    begin
        -- add --
        wait for 30 ns;
        abc<="000"; def<="000"; wait for 10 ns; -- zero
        abc<="000"; def<="001"; wait for 10 ns; -- one
        abc<="001"; def<="001"; wait for 10 ns; -- one
        abc<="010"; def<="001"; wait for 10 ns; -- three
        abc<="011"; def<="001"; wait for 10 ns; -- four
        abc<="001"; def<="100"; wait for 10 ns; -- five
        abc<="100"; def<="010"; wait for 10 ns; -- six
        abc<="011"; def<="100"; wait for 10 ns; -- seven
        abc<="011"; def<="101"; wait for 20 ns; -- eight

        -- subtract --
        wait for 30 ns;  
        OP<='1';abc<="010"; def<="010"; wait for 10 ns; -- zero
        OP<='1';abc<="100"; def<="101"; wait for 10 ns; -- neg one
        OP<='1';abc<="001"; def<="011"; wait for 10 ns; -- neg two
        OP<='1';abc<="100"; def<="111"; wait for 10 ns; -- neg three 
        OP<='1';abc<="010"; def<="110"; wait for 10 ns; -- neg four
        OP<='1';abc<="001"; def<="110"; wait for 20 ns; -- neg five

    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] (lacking the entity and architecture for AddSub_1_wrapper) your VHDL code can't be validated here. There are obvious problems. The expression for the actual `abc(3)` has an index out of range of the signal object `abc`, so does `def(3)` for signal `def`. I'd suspect without seeing AddSub_1_wrapper those should be `A_0 => abc(0), A_1 => abc(1), A_2 => abc(2),`  and `B_0 = >def(0), B_1 => def(1),B_2 => def(2),`. For those of us without Vivado Sim what does your Tcl console output say? (Add the [tag:vivado] tag).

Comment: I apologize, here is what the 'elaborate' file says: Vivado Simulator 2018.2 
Using 2 slave threads.
Starting static elaboration
ERROR: [VRFC 10-923] index value <3> is out of range [2:0] of array <abc> [C:/Users/jstev/Desktop/lab_2.1/lab_2.1.srcs/sim_1/new/addSub_TestBench.vhd:41]
ERROR: [VRFC 10-923] index value <3> is out of range [2:0] of array <def> [C:/Users/jstev/Desktop/lab_2.1/lab_2.1.srcs/sim_1/new/addSub_TestBench.vhd:42]
ERROR: [XSIM 43-3322] Static elaboration of top level Verilog design unit(s) in library work failed.

Comment: I did not even notice I had the incorrect numbers in the vector position, thank you! I am trying to rerun the simulation now. Also, where can I find the entity and architecture information you are looking for?

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thank you for your help!!